# MongoDB index and query strategy to fetch a record within range bounded by two fields

Tags: mongodb, performance, query-optimization, database-performance

Our IP address ranges table has ~2.8 million records, of the following structure:

```js
{
  start_ip: integer,    // IPv4 converted to int32
  end_ip: integer,      // IPv4 converted to int32
  country_code: string,
  country: string,
  region: string,
  city: string
}
```

There is a compound index on `start_ip` and `end_ip`:

```js
{ start_ip: 1, end_ip: 1 }
```

To get records from the table (read: to know what range the given IP belongs to) we use this query:

```js
{"start_ip"=>{"$lte"=>3284004939}, "end_ip"=>{"$gte"=>3284004939}}
```

However we observe an unacceptably low performance of the query. Here is the `explain` example:

```js
{
  "explainVersion": "2",
  "queryPlanner": {
    "namespace": "restclass_development.ip_ranges",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "start_ip": {
            "$lte": 3284004939
          }
        },
        {
          "end_ip": {
            "$gte": 3284004939
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "queryHash": "379E557D",
    "planCacheKey": "E1838ADA",
    "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
    "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
    "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
    "winningPlan": {
      "queryPlan": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "planNodeId": 2,
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "planNodeId": 1,
          "keyPattern": {
            "start_ip": 1,
            "end_ip": 1
          },
          "indexName": "start_ip_1_end_ip_1",
          "isMultiKey": false,
          "multiKeyPaths": {
            "start_ip": [],
            "end_ip": []
          },
          "isUnique": false,
          "isSparse": false,
          "isPartial": false,
          "indexVersion": 2,
          "direction": "forward",
          "indexBounds": {
            "start_ip": [
              "[-inf.0, 3284004939]"
            ],
            "end_ip": [
              "[3284004939, inf.0]"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "slotBasedPlan": {
        "slots": "$$RESULT=s25 env: { s9 = {\"start_ip\" : 1, \"end_ip\" : 1}, s5 = IndexBounds(\"field #0['start_ip']: [-inf.0, 3284004939], field #1['end_ip']: [3284004939, inf.0]\"), s3 = 1699191077268 (NOW), s24 = true, s1 = TimeZoneDatabase(Africa/Ceuta...Etc/GMT-12) (timeZoneDB), s2 = Nothing (SEARCH_META), s13 = Nothing }",
        "stages": "[2] nlj inner [] [s19, s20, s21, s22, s23] \n    left \n        [1] branch {s24} [s19, s20, s21, s22, s23] \n        [s4, s6, s7, s8, s9] [1] ixscan_generic s5 s8 s4 s6 s7 lowPriority [] @\"99a3fa22-8459-4875-bbc9-3cf3ee9afc55\" @\"start_ip_1_end_ip_1\" true \n        [s10, s16, s17, s18, s9] [1] nlj inner [] [s11, s12] \n            left \n                [1] project [s11 = getField(s14, \"l\"), s12 = getField(s14, \"h\")] \n                [1] unwind s14 s15 s13 false \n                [1] limit 1 \n                [1] coscan \n            right \n                [1] ixseek s11 s12 s18 s10 s16 s17 [] @\"99a3fa22-8459-4875-bbc9-3cf3ee9afc55\" @\"start_ip_1_end_ip_1\" true \n    right \n        [2] limit 1 \n        [2] seek s19 s25 s26 s20 s21 s22 s23 [] @\"99a3fa22-8459-4875-bbc9-3cf3ee9afc55\" true false \n"
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": []
  },
  "executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 1,
    "executionTimeMillis": 1276,
    "totalKeysExamined": 2422998,
    "totalDocsExamined": 1,
    "executionStages": {
      "stage": "nlj",
      "planNodeId": 2,
      "nReturned": 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1276,
      "opens": 1,
      "closes": 1,
      "saveState": 1,
      "restoreState": 1,
      "isEOF": 1,
      "totalDocsExamined": 1,
      "totalKeysExamined": 2422998,
      "collectionScans": 0,
      "collectionSeeks": 1,
      "indexScans": 0,
      "indexSeeks": 1,
      "indexesUsed": [
        "start_ip_1_end_ip_1",
        "start_ip_1_end_ip_1"
      ],
      "innerOpens": 1,
      "innerCloses": 1,
      "outerProjects": [],
      "outerCorrelated": [
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23
      ],
      "outerStage": {
        "stage": "branch",
        "planNodeId": 1,
        "nReturned": 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1276,
        "opens": 1,
        "closes": 1,
        "saveState": 1,
        "restoreState": 1,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "numTested": 1,
        "thenBranchOpens": 1,
        "thenBranchCloses": 1,
        "elseBranchOpens": 0,
        "elseBranchCloses": 0,
        "filter": "s24 ",
        "thenSlots": [
          4,
          6,
          7,
          8,
          9
        ],
        "elseSlots": [
          10,
          16,
          17,
          18,
          9
        ],
        "outputSlots": [
          19,
          20,
          21,
          22,
          23
        ],
        "thenStage": {
          "stage": "ixscan_generic",
          "planNodeId": 1,
          "nReturned": 1,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1276,
          "opens": 1,
          "closes": 1,
          "saveState": 1,
          "restoreState": 1,
          "isEOF": 1,
          "indexName": "start_ip_1_end_ip_1",
          "keysExamined": 2422998,
          "seeks": 2422997,
          "numReads": 2422998,
          "indexKeySlot": 8,
          "recordIdSlot": 4,
          "snapshotIdSlot": 6,
          "indexIdentSlot": 7,
          "outputSlots": [],
          "indexKeysToInclude": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        },
        "elseStage": {
          "stage": "nlj",
          "planNodeId": 1,
          "nReturned": 0,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
          "opens": 0,
          "closes": 0,
          "saveState": 1,
          "restoreState": 1,
          "isEOF": 0,
          "totalDocsExamined": 0,
          "totalKeysExamined": 0,
          "collectionScans": 0,
          "collectionSeeks": 0,
          "indexScans": 0,
          "indexSeeks": 0,
          "indexesUsed": [
            "start_ip_1_end_ip_1"
          ],
          "innerOpens": 0,
          "innerCloses": 0,
          "outerProjects": [],
          "outerCorrelated": [
            11,
            12
          ],
          "outerStage": {
            "stage": "project",
            "planNodeId": 1,
            "nReturned": 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "opens": 0,
            "closes": 0,
            "saveState": 1,
            "restoreState": 1,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "projections": {
              "11": "getField(s14, \"l\") ",
              "12": "getField(s14, \"h\") "
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "unwind",
              "planNodeId": 1,
              "nReturned": 0,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
              "opens": 0,
              "closes": 0,
              "saveState": 1,
              "restoreState": 1,
              "isEOF": 0,
              "inputSlot": 13,
              "outSlot": 14,
              "outIndexSlot": 15,
              "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": 0,
              "inputStage": {
                "stage": "limit",
                "planNodeId": 1,
                "nReturned": 0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                "opens": 0,
                "closes": 0,
                "saveState": 1,
                "restoreState": 1,
                "isEOF": 0,
                "limit": 1,
                "inputStage": {
                  "stage": "coscan",
                  "planNodeId": 1,
                  "nReturned": 0,
                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                  "opens": 0,
                  "closes": 0,
                  "saveState": 1,
                  "restoreState": 1,
                  "isEOF": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "innerStage": {
            "stage": "ixseek",
            "planNodeId": 1,
            "nReturned": 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "opens": 0,
            "closes": 0,
            "saveState": 1,
            "restoreState": 1,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "indexName": "start_ip_1_end_ip_1",
            "keysExamined": 0,
            "seeks": 0,
            "numReads": 0,
            "indexKeySlot": 18,
            "recordIdSlot": 10,
            "snapshotIdSlot": 16,
            "indexIdentSlot": 17,
            "outputSlots": [],
            "indexKeysToInclude": "00000000000000000000000000000000",
            "seekKeyLow": "s11 ",
            "seekKeyHigh": "s12 "
          }
        }
      },
      "innerStage": {
        "stage": "limit",
        "planNodeId": 2,
        "nReturned": 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "opens": 1,
        "closes": 1,
        "saveState": 1,
        "restoreState": 1,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "limit": 1,
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "seek",
          "planNodeId": 2,
          "nReturned": 1,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
          "opens": 1,
          "closes": 1,
          "saveState": 1,
          "restoreState": 1,
          "isEOF": 0,
          "numReads": 1,
          "recordSlot": 25,
          "recordIdSlot": 26,
          "seekKeySlot": 19,
          "snapshotIdSlot": 20,
          "indexIdentSlot": 21,
          "indexKeySlot": 22,
          "indexKeyPatternSlot": 23,
          "fields": [],
          "outputSlots": []
        }
      }
    },
    "allPlansExecution": []
  },
  "command": {
    "find": "ip_ranges",
    "filter": {
      "start_ip": {
        "$lte": 3284004939
      },
      "end_ip": {
        "$gte": 3284004939
      }
    },
    "$db": "restclass_development"
  },
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "sun.arg.network",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "7.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a"
  },
  "serverParameters": {
    "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
    "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFrameworkControl": "trySbeEngine"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

This query is executed in ~1.5 seconds. What would be a more time efficient query and/or indexing strategy for our use case?

Comment: What sort of distribution of integers do we find in the 2.8m records?   Guessing there is no overlap and in particular, a single IP (like your example) should yield one record only?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti there is no overlap, the query will always return a single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### NOTE:  This is a non-orthodox approach to solving the problem.

First, acknowledgements to John Page (https://www.mongodb.com/developer/author/john-page), one of the all-time MongoDB greats, for first exploring this approach.

Often we encounter data range challenges in our data design and querying.  The OP has approached this in the traditional way:  create two fields, start_THING and end_THING, set up a compound key on the fields, and use `start_THING $lte target` and `end_THING $gte target` to quickly find one doc.  Or, to find things in a range, `start_THING $gte lowerBound` and `end_THING $lt upperBound`.

Another way to do this is by using a *single geospatial* field with a `2dsphere` index on it.   Here's how this approach would work in the context of the OP data:

- IPv4 addresses start at `0.0.0.0` and go to `255.255.255.255`.   The OP notes that a conversion to integer is clearly possible.  The range of IPs in integer terms is `0` to `4294967295` (256 ** 4).
- Consider the IP range `10.3.232.0` to `10.3.232.5`.  This is `168028160` and `168028165` in integer terms, respectively.
- Instead of storing 2 fields, we scale these integers to the range of *longitudes* (-180.0 to 180.0) as follows (all numbers including constants shown to provide clarity:

```
    geo_start = ((168028160 / 4294967295) * (180 - (-180))) + (-180);
    geo_end = ((168028165 / 4294967295) * (180 - (-180))) + (-180);
```

- We then store these in a single geo field; note the latitude is essentially unused and set to 0.0:

```
    geo: { type: "LineString", coordinates: [ [ geo_start, 0.0 ], [geo_end, 0.0 ] ] }
```

Here is an example of a data record fully populated:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6549055e795d8927e4779193"),
  N: 1000,
  start_ip: '10.3.232.0',
  end_ip: '10.3.232.5',
  int_start_ip: 168028160,
  int_end_ip: 168028165,
  geo: {
    type: 'LineString',
    coordinates: [ [ -165.91604232460168, 0 ], [ -165.91604190550652, 0 ] ]
  },
  country_code: 'XXX',
  country: 'Xland',
  region: 'Mars',
  city: 'Foo'
}
```

- We index the field with:

```
    db.foo.createIndex({geo:"2dsphere"})
```

- Now it is possible to lookup an item by converting a start and/or end IP to scaled longitude and using `$geoIntersects`:

```
    function convertToGeo(sip) {
        q = sip.split('.');

        var iip = 0;
        for(var n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
            iip += (parseInt(q[n]) * (256 ** (3 - n)));
        }
        return ((iip / new NumberLong("4294967295")) * 360 ) - 180 ;
    }

    var gsip = convertToGeo('10.232.0.3'); // .3 is in between .0 and .5; see data record above
    var xx = db.foo.findOne({
        geo: {
            $geoIntersects: {
                $geometry: { type: "LineString",
                     // Must create a second discrete point for a line, so make it 0.1
                     coordinates: [ [ gsip, 0.0 ], gsip, 0.1 ] ] }
            }
        }
    };
    // The doc above is found!
```

Sampling 100 random IPs in a population of 3m items show the single geo index approach working *much* faster than the compound index approach, typically taking no more than 1 millisecond:

```
100 samples of GEO approach:
{
  count: 100,
  execMillis_min: 0,
  execMillis_max: 1,
  execMillis_tot: 16,
  execMillis_avg: 0,
  totKeysExamined_min: 296,
  totKeysExamined_max: 648,
  totKeysExamined_tot: 48327,
  totKeysExamined_avg: 3.744628643254086,
  totDocsExamined_min: 222,
  totDocsExamined_max: 556,
  totDocsExamined_tot: 39977,
  totDocsExamined_avg: 2.806450990888347
}
One of the explains:
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
  ...
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        keyPattern: { geo: '2dsphere' },
        indexName: 'geo_2dsphere',

  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 1,
    executionTimeMillis: 1,
    totalKeysExamined: 353,
    totalDocsExamined: 266,
        keysExamined: 353,
        seeks: 21,
        dupsTested: 332,
        dupsDropped: 66
      }
    },
 ...
}
```

```
100 samples of COMPOUND start/end approach:
{
  count: 100,
  execMillis_min: 48,
  execMillis_max: 1360,
  execMillis_tot: 63096,
  execMillis_avg: 630.96,
  totKeysExamined_min: 10000,
  totKeysExamined_max: 2859339,
  totKeysExamined_tot: 137167079,
  totKeysExamined_avg: 19980.70323149996,
  totDocsExamined_min: 1,
  totDocsExamined_max: 1,
  totDocsExamined_tot: 100,
  totDocsExamined_avg: 0.010102051554122065
}

One of the explains:
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        keyPattern: {
          int_start_ip: 1,
          int_end_ip: 1
        },
        indexName: 'int_start_ip_1_int_end_ip_1',
  ...
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 1,
    executionTimeMillis: 1051,
    totalKeysExamined: 2311153,
    totalDocsExamined: 1,
        keysExamined: 2311153,
        seeks: 2311152,
        dupsTested: 0,
        dupsDropped: 0
}
```

Some more tests now in tabular form.  The `2dsphere` index strategy clearly benefits when looking up material "further down" the range of values:

```
  db.foo.find({int_start_ip:{$lte:int_target}, int_end_ip:{$gte:int_target}}).explain(true);               
                                                                                                   
      N  totMS   keysExam docsExam  seeks                                                          
      2      0         4       1        3                                                          
 500000    235    500002       1   500001                                                          
3000000   1322   3000002       1  3000001                                                          
5000000   2301   5000002       1  5000001                                                          
9999999   4710  10000000       1 10000000                                                          
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
db.foo.find({geo: {'$geoIntersects': {'$geometry': {                                               
                      type: 'LineString',                                                          
                      coordinates: [ [ geo_target,0 ], [ geo_target,0.1 ] ]                                
                      }}}}).explain(true);   
                                                                    
      N  totMS   keysExam docsExam  seeks                                                                                                                                                             
      2      1       200     130        8                                                          
 500000      1       256     276       11                                                          
3000000      3       621     530       23                                                          
5000000      2       621     533       13                                                          
9999999      0        39      15        9
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This approach blew my mind. The original example IP lookup now takes few milliseconds with `executionTimeMillis: 1`.

Answer (score 0):

On a MacBook Pro M2 Max 64GB machine running mongod 6.0.4, 3m documents in a collection with a uniform distribution of IP ranges, executing

```
db.foo.find({start_ip:{$lte:190000}, end_ip:{$gte:190000}}).explain(true);
```

*without* an index yields:

```
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 1,
    **executionTimeMillis: 564**,
    totalKeysExamined: 0,
    totalDocsExamined: 3000000,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'COLLSCAN',
```

With index:

```
db.foo.createIndex({start_ip:1, end_ip:1});
```

yields:

```
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 1,
    **executionTimeMillis: 17**,
    totalKeysExamined: 19002,
    totalDocsExamined: 1,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      nReturned: 1,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 1,
      works: 19002,
      advanced: 1,
      needTime: 19000,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 19,
      restoreState: 19,
      isEOF: 1,
      docsExamined: 1,
      alreadyHasObj: 0,
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        nReturned: 1,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 1,
```

3m docs of this size (avg 120 bytes) is "small" both non-indexed and indexed fetches reflect same.  Are you sure you're not somehow dragging back 1000s or more docs and the delay is in the network transmission?

Comment: I don't think this is a very apples-to-apples comparison. Try using `2810000` (3,000,000 - 190,000) or `2596058` (~86% of the collection, similar to OP's 2.4M out of 2.8M) as the filter value. I'd also be interested in the seeks that are happening in your test which are cut off from the output currently provided

Comment: @user20042973  Great point; thx.  Using `2810000`  I get `executionTimeMillis: 126, totalKeysExamined: 24230,  keysExamined: 281002, seeks: 281001`.   Still zippy.